# iOS: Maximum memory in simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I start my app in the simulator it crashes immediately with "error: memory read failed"

Everything works fine on iPad/iPhone, but the when I add a simple "return;" before the core data lines, the simulator starts up fine:

```
return;
CCAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

IMPORTANT!!:
It does not run that code at any time, just compiles it. And if I add the "return;" before the same core data connection in another file instead, it runs fine to. Looks like there is some kind of maximum "connection" to core data or something?

I have tried Cleaning Xcode (Normal and clean build folder), cleaning the simulator (Reset content and setting), but with no success.

Additional question: Is there someway I can re-install IOS simulator?

Comment: Found out that it is the amount of code lines in the project. If I remove some lines (or just add a return;) else where in the project, then simulator does not crash. Really weird!! When I write code and it crashes on start, -I just remove (rem) code somewhere in the project, that I dont need for now, and it run fine again... ?!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

"error: memory read failed". I received same message this morning. And I found it id related to Block.

As we know, if a class has a Block as its member, it ought to be look like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy)BlockType block;
```

And my mistake was forgot to use copy when add a block to a NSArray instance:

```
[array addObject:aBlock];
```

Finally I solved it by this:

```
MyBlockType copy = [aBlock copy];
[array addObject:copy];
[copy release];
```

Good luck!

Upate Mar/20/1013
Another situation causes "error: memory read failed".

```
- (void)blockCalledMethod{
    for (BlockType b in _dictionary) {
        b(self);
    }
}
```

The key to solve my problem is to iterate NSDictionary by using .allKeys.
But the object in dictionary is Block, so it must be relative with Block.

Comment: Any idea how you debugged this and found out it was to do with the block?

Comment: No idea.I found out because after I fixed it my code works well.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue with my iPhone simulator. I have clean code in XCode

[image]

and i have reset simulator

[image]

Hope it will help